# How do I create a custom title bar and window in Expression Blend, WPF?

Tags: wpf, user-interface, expression-blend, blend

I need to create a custom title bar, and to include all the usual window functions such as Maximise, Minimise, and Close, and for the title bar to be the part to drag the window.  Also, I need the usual resizing functionality.

I've found some articles, but they don't seem to give the whole solution.  I've selected Allow Transparency, and then created my own titlebar (it is just a rectangle) but I don't know how to give it the dragging function.  Also, the window cannot be resized.

In short, could you tell me how to 1) add Max, Min, Close functions to buttons I create, 2) give my title bar the ability to drag the window, and 3) the ability to resize from all sides and corners

Many thanks in advance

Comment: best bet is take something like [Mahapps Metro](http://mahapps.com/MahApps.Metro/) and either use it or see how they implement the exact same thing and do it yourself.

Comment: you can choose to just use the chrome-less `Window` part of Mahapps metro, think it's called `MetroWindow` which gives you all your looking for, You do not have to take the other bits if you do not want to ofc.

Comment: thanks viv, I'm going through it now, although it seems a bit of an overkill, isn't there a simple way to assign these windows functions within Blend?

Comment: I've just installed it, but I'm a bit concerned as I didn't want to add anything extraneous into this project.  Is this worth it?  I'd rather just keep everything as clean and native as possible. thanks

Comment: How about [this one](http://www.kirupa.com/blend_wpf/custom_wpf_windows.htm)? this is pretty minimalistic.